# Remove Decimal from BigDecimal

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

I have a BigDecimal number, I just want to remove the decimal numbers from it,
for example if I have 200.88 then output should be 200? 
I tried Bigdecimal rounding function but they wont do the job

Comment: I bet you forgot the roundingMode

Comment: Math.floor(200.88) - for lower bound value or Math.ceil(200.88) - For upper bound value

Comment: I did this, BigDecimal bg1 = new BigDecimal(300.99);
               bg1.setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR); it returns  300.99000000000000909494701772928237915039062

Comment: Never, ever initialize a BigDecimal with a double, if you can avoid it. Use `BigDecimal bg1 = new BigDecimal("300.99");` instead. Doubles are only approximations, hence the "unexpected" result. And do `bg1 = bg1.setScale(etc...);`. BigDecimals are immutable and `setScale()` returns a *new* BigDecimal, it does not modify its target.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the rounding mode to `ROUND_FLOOR` when you use `round`.

Comment: I did this, BigDecimal bg1 = new BigDecimal(300.99);
               bg1.setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR); it returns  300.99000000000000909494701772928237915039062

Comment: Works fine for me. Remember that `BigDecimal` is an immutable class so you have to store the result of `setScale`.

Comment: that worked ,I was not storing the result. Thanks for the Help